# Can't sign my AIR application for iTunes connect to accept it

Tags: ios, air, sign

This should have been the easy bit.... Having spend weeks developing an AIR application (using a developer certificate) the big day arrived to upload the App to the AppStore for review. That was Sunday everning (48 hours ago) and since then I've been trying to get my App passed the "Apple Application Loader" without any luck. I normally work on a Windows machine but have also tried the Mac Key Chain approach without any luck so here is my cry for help. So the steps I followed  are:

- Download XCode to my Mac
- Use CS5.5 on my PC
- Develop application with AIR for IOS / ActionScript 3.0
- Follow these instructions: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff0.html
- in summary - using SSL installed on a Ubuntu 10.04 box

  - "openssl genrsa -out mykey.key 2048"
  - "openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest  -subj "/emailAddress=[MY_APPLE_EMAIL], CN=[MY_NAME], C=US"
  - Upload: CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest as my Distribution Key to my iOS Provisioning portal
  - Download the "Distribution certificate" to my Ubuntu server (I don't seem to have a use for the WWDR file - should I use that somehow?)
  - Convert the Distribution certificate to a PEM file using: openssl x509 -in distribution_identity.cer -inform DER -out distribution_identity.pem -outform PEM
  - Convert PEM to a P12 file: openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in distribution_identity.pem -out iphone_dist.p12
  - Create a new distribution profile on iOS developer site using this new distribution certificate and download it
- In CS5.5 - Publishing profile - Player Development settings

  - use iphone_dist.p12 as the development certificate
  - use the downloaded distribution profile as the provisioning profile
  - Set the deployment type to "Apple App Store"
    Publish

I get a nice and shiny ipa file which I then put on my mac and try to upload it using Application Loader which rejects it with:

***Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate***

I've tried to regenerate everything about 20 times now on Mac and Windows but always with the same result. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

3 Days later - I figured it out and for the  rest of the world who will ever try to do the same thing:

- I use CS5.5 to develop my Apps which comes with AIR 2.6
- Air 2.6 runs like a (slow) dog on iPhones so I installed AIR 3.1 and I created a seperate XML / and windows Batch file to compile to AIR 3.1
- That Batch file include an  tag which was just a tiny little bit different to the one specified in iOS Developer Portal / iTunes Connect - and that breaks the verification process in App Loader

So moral of the story is: Make sure that

**iTunes Connect Bundle ID = iOS Developer AppID (without the first 10 or so digits) = CS5.5 Publish Setting - Deployment - AppID**

Or loose lots of sleep :-)